# How to fix OSError: [WinError 123] when publishing to PyPi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi, pypiserver

Full error:

> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\Program Files\GDAL"'

Why is Python looking for the file C:\Program Files\GDAL" when I run the following?

`python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`

I even created a folder named GDAL in my C:/Program files folder, but it's still not working? Why in the world must uploading a package to PyPi be such a pain?!?

Comment: Sounds like something to do with `twine`. Try reinstalling `twine` and see if it still happens; do you have anything in your script which uses a path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out - turns out my PYTHONPATH variable was set to C:\Program Files\GDAL" for some unknown reason. I changed it to C:\Users\\Anaconda3 and now it works!